# Random color each time button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like for the div to change to a random color generated by my `makeColor` variable every time the button is clicked. Thanks in advance.

```
var makeColor ="#" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 999) + 1);

$("button").click(function(){
  $("div").css("background",makeColor);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a function for this task

```js
function randomColor() {
    var c = "#";
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        c += (Math.random() * 16 | 0).toString(16);
    } 
    return c;
}

var a = document.getElementById("id1").style;
a.color = randomColor();
```

```html
<h1 id="id1">stackoverflow</h1>
```